# JSoup html parsing - download only some part of html page (not whole) before parsing?

Tags: android, html, html-parsing, jsoup

I've an app, which is parsing some html page. Now I'm doing it in this way:

1. I load whole html (without resources of course, just pure html)
2. I parse only elements which I need (this is small part of page)
3. do some work on this

What I need is to **do not donwload complete html** as it is pretty big and I need only small portion of it - I would like to **download only some part of web page**, is this possible? It's because of fact, that on mobiles are usually much slower internet connection, and there are also much smaller data limits.

Comment: Dont use code blocks for statements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to, say, download just the middle of the page, that's not possible.  You could potentially stream the first n bytes of data using URLConnection and the inputstream provided if you knew the data you needed was within the first n bytes.  Then convert the contents of that stream into a String that you can feed into JSoup and hope it can parse that fragment.

Answer (score 1):

You can parse the elements you need then use "Jsoup.parseBodyFragment()" method.

You can refer to http://jsoup.org/cookbook/input/parse-body-fragment